# Getting UiView tag when touched

Tags: ios, swift

I have developed a UIView from For loop and basically it is create 3 Views from loop. and I have to add touch gesture on every View to call a method but I am unable to get current selected UIView.tag when I tap on it. it is only showing the .tag of the last view. here is my code.

```
    for i in 0 ... 2 {
            let productView = UIView()
                productView.tag = i
                productView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                let producttap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.ProductTapped))
                productView.addGestureRecognizer(producttap)
                productView.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: scView1.frame.size.height)
                xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + productView.frame.size.width
                scView1.addSubview(productView)
            productIndex = productView.tag
}
```

and here is the method that I am calling from every UIView touch.

```
@objc func ProductTapped() {
        print("",productIndex)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be using delegate/callback closure, but if you want to keep using tag, try change it to:

```
    @objc func ProductTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = sender.view {
            print(view.tag)
        }
    }
```

and the gesture attach to `let producttap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.ProductTapped(_:)))`

`productIndex` does nothing here since it got overwritten on the loop

Comment: output is "Optional(0)" how can I make it show only "0"

Comment: You should unwrap the optional first, updated the answer for that

Comment: @VixHunk `if let view = sender.view, let tag = view.tag { print(tag) }`

Answer (score 0):

`productIndex` currently has no relationship to the tap gestures that you attach your views. You do set `productIndex` in the the loop but that's irrelevant to your gesture.

Perhaps you want

```
let producttap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(productTapped(_:))
```

and

```
@objc func productTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tag is",gesture.view.tag)
}
```